# How to copy a table to another table using linq

Tags: sql, linq

I remember when we work with SQL Commands we could copy a table data to another same table with a simple code like this :

```
INSERT INTO table1 (f1, f2, f3)

SELECT     f1, f2, f3

FROM         table2
```

now how can I do like this in linq? i did with foreach but in high range data it takes to many time to do my command about 7 - 8 minutes.
but with this SQL commend it copies in 2 - 3 seconds.

someone help me.

thank you

Comment: LINQ is not a magic wand. It essentially does the same as your foreach.

Comment: So you mean SQL is magic wand? @GertArnold

Comment: If you like. You seem to expect some magical performance increase from LINQ. Won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but try something like the following. Two entities (ENT1 and ENT2 with identical fields). UPDATED to show use of Automapper.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ENT1, ENT2>();
var query1 = dbContext.ENT1;
var query2 = dbContext.ENT2;
query2.AddRange(Mapper.Map<List<ENT1>, List<ENT2>>(query1));
dbContext.Update();
```

If the two entities have primary keys you might have to limit the selections to all fields apart from the PKs.

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.Table1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Models.Table2>'

Comment: You might need to use Automapper, which will accept lists as arguements. I'll update the example.